# Stripe API for node js. Creating a new charge object

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services, stripe-payments

I'm trying to set up a new new charge object using Stripe API. I have followed the [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#create_charge) and came up with this:

```
stripe.charges.create({
    amount: args.amount,
    currency: "usd",
    source: args.source, // obtained with Stripe.js
    description: args.description
}, function(err, charge) {
    if(err) {
        return cb(true);
    } else {
        console.log('Successful charge sent to Stripe!');
        cb(false)
    }
});
```

(cb is callback function that handles the outcome), args.source is a string. According to package.json I'm using stripe API v3.7.1. 
 I always get this error:

```
Error: Stripe: Unknown arguments ([object Object]). Did you mean to pass an options object? See https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/wiki/Passing-Options.
at Object.create (/home/uria/Rapid/RapidAPIEngine/node_modules/stripe/lib/StripeMethod.js:57:13)
at Stripe.charge (/home/uria/Rapid/RapidAPIEngine/functionalAPI/stripe.js:20:33)
at Object.module.exports.charge.execute (/home/uria/Rapid/RapidAPIEngine/Block_Endpoint/packages/stripe.js:7:26)
at Endpoint.executionLoop (/home/uria/Rapid/RapidAPIEngine/Block_Endpoint/Endpoint.js:163:11)
at Endpoint.run (/home/uria/Rapid/RapidAPIEngine/Block_Endpoint/Endpoint.js:93:10)
at /home/uria/Rapid/RapidAPIEngine/index.js:223:96
at handleCallback (/home/uria/Rapid/RapidAPIEngine/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:95:12)
at /home/uria/Rapid/RapidAPIEngine/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:1122:5
at handleCallback (/home/uria/Rapid/RapidAPIEngine/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:95:12)
at /home/uria/Rapid/RapidAPIEngine/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:597:5
at handleCallback (/home/uria/Rapid/RapidAPIEngine/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:244:5)
at nextFunction (/home/uria/Rapid/RapidAPIEngine/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:739:5)
at /home/uria/Rapid/RapidAPIEngine/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:664:7
at queryCallback (/home/uria/Rapid/RapidAPIEngine/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:321:5)
at Callbacks.emit (/home/uria/Rapid/RapidAPIEngine/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:95:3)
at null.messageHandler (/home/uria/Rapid/RapidAPIEngine/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:243:23)
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: can you add the following code, how you are calling the function in which this code exists and this function total code. Problem might be due to incorrect parameter length

Comment: is args.source an object or a string? Which version of the Stripe-Node api library are you using?